# getJSON call fails unless single stepped

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, getjson

I have a application that has a home page w/ a form w/ check boxes; the chk-bxs represent column-data to return from a MySQL db.

The behavior I’m trying to achieve is:

1. User checks / unchecks boxes on home page
2. User clicks link to page that will run the query
3. Server receives the check boxes states through a getJSON call,
   triggered by the unload of the home page.  PHP loads $_SESSION[] w/
   chk-bxs states
4. Server then process the link call using the data in $_SESSION[] to
   determine what column data to return and display in result in a
   table

I CAN achieve this IF I put a break point at the last member assign of the getJSON call and single stepping it.  Without the single-step, the getJSON call doesn’t seem to happen;  so the chk-bxs values don’t get transmitted to the server.
Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is there a better way to approach the problem?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

This is the code in the head section of the index.php file that calls the function that will do the getJSON call:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
indexFormUnload(); // this saves the state of the SELECT check-boxes
});
```

This is the code that constructs the getJSON call - it resides in a separate file included in the index.php file:

```
function indexFormUnload(){
var ckBxValues = $(":input").serializeArray();
$.getJSON("ajaxJQ_server.php", // server page called by jquery
{ // Data sent via ajaxJQ
"callingForm": "index",
"callingElementID" : null,
"locStorage": ckBxValues,
"callingState": "unload",
"tableName": null
}
);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there's an AJAX that finishes too late if the code is not single-stepped. Can we see your code?

Comment: Perhaps the getJSON itself does not get waited for to finish.

Comment: If you send an AJAX from a page unload handler (or unprevented submit handler), then the page gets unloaded before the AJAX has the chance to leave.

Comment: More than likely you are coding as-if getJSON were synchronous, but it is asynchronous. Without code, there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: @KevinB That, or the unload handler ("... through a getJSON call, triggered by the unload")

Comment: @JanDvorak If it were synchronous, would it finish before the unload is completed? probably not, but it may be worth testing.

Comment: I've added the code to the post. -- Mike

Answer (score 0):

When the browser closes it kills all of the open connections. They do that for performance. You have a race condition and you will not win most of the time. There is no way to make sure the call is made to the server. There used to be a way to do it with a while loop, but browsers killed that.

Comment: What about preventing the unload? It's possible with a submit. Would a simple unload confirmation dialog tip the race in favor of the AJAX?

Comment: I suspected that this is some sort of race condition but wanted to ask a general question in case there was something that I wasn't doing correctly or perhaps a different feature I wasn't taking advantage of. Unless there is some other miraculous answer that appears I'll start to engineer a different solution - perhaps attaching getJSON calls to each of the check boxes.  --- Mike